# Adafruit Oled library causing my esp8266 to crash

Tags: crash, esp8266, arduino-c++

today I wanted to try to use a oled display with esp8266 using arduino language. Before I always used micropython to use an oled display. I had written a long code but it kept showing error. Then I decided to comment out the code that I used for the oled display. Then the error disappeared. Can someone please help me solve that problem?
My code :

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>

//netwok
const char* ssid = "Iffaiman";
const char* password = "iffaiman313";
//oled var
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 128 // OLED display width, in pixels
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 64 // OLED display height, in pixels
// Declaration for an SSD1306 display connected to I2C (SDA, SCL pins)
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, &Wire, -1);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(1000);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi...");
  }

  Serial.println("Connected to WiFi");
  display.println("Hello, world!");
  display.display();
}

void loop() {
}
```

The error message:
`xception (28): epc1=0x40201e0a epc2=0x00000000 epc3=0x00000000 excvaddr=0x00000000 depc=0x00000000`

I tried to remove any optional code but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is crashing because you're not calling the `begin()` method on the `display` object. That means it's not initialized, so its behavior is undefined.

You need to call the `begin()` method before doing anything else with the display.

```
Serial.println("Connected to WiFi");
if(!display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, SCREEN_ADDRESS)) {
  Serial.println("Can't find display");
  while(1)
    yield();
}

display.println("Hello, world!");
display.display();
```

`SCREEN_ADDRESS` should be the I2C address of the SSD1306, either 0x3C or 0x3D.

Adafruit publishes extensive [examples](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_SSD1306/tree/master/examples) and [tutorials](https://learn.adafruit.com/monochrome-oled-breakouts) on how to use their products and libraries. These are a very good place to start when you're having problems with the hardware or software.